# Can Vette be corrupted?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I've heard rumors that if you keep Vette's shock collar on, and shock her every chance you get, then she will eventually become twisted and start to prefer the dark side dialogue choices that she normally dislikes.  Can anyone confirm if this is true?

In my case, I've gotten to the point where I keep getting the same dialogue cutscene with her, where she demands that I take the collar off, and if I shock her she says something like "fine, but don't expect any more help from me".  I've heard from people that she will continue giving this same cutscene over and over until I remove the collar, which clearly contradicts the other rumors that I described above.

However, my affection with her is still low (just below 1000), so I'm not sure if I'm stuck on this cutscene because the rumors of being able to corrupt Vette are untrue, or just because I need to artificially raise her affection in order to proceed with the corruption.

Comment: Nothing I can find on the bajillions of wikis, forums, or blogs that I have been through support this theory *but* that doesn't mean that it is wrong. . . .

Answer (score 4):

The article Neil links to is incorrect; [Vette cannot be turned to the dark side](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=209407).  However the male Sith Warrior can pursue some romance options with her [that involve some "dark" stuff with her shock collar](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jiTyR1syrS0) (potentially NSFW depending on your work environment).  That may be the source of the confusion.

The Sith Warrior also gets another female companion, Jaesa Willsaam, [who *can* be turned either Dark or made permanently Light](http://www.swtor.com/fr/community/showthread.php?t=239935).  Again that might be the source of the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently yes she can, and at the time of writing, she is the only "corruptible / redeemable" companion character in the game.

- [gamingfeeds.com article.](http://swtor.gamingfeeds.com/2011/12/28/thom%E2%80%99s-thought-transmissions-what-do-you-care-about/)

Comment: I'm extremely disappointed that Bioware doesn't have more compelling reasons like this to play on the Republic side.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not.
I have kept the collar on all the way up to affection 9000 and she just repeats the same cutscene each time.

Comment: 10,000 is the max, not sure that 9,000 indicates anything.  But see my answer.